# Custom Flag Declined Without Explanation - Why?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

First and foremost: I'm not trying to be in any way 'narky' about this - just looking for information and/or guidance.

Second: I recently posted this (incorrectly) as an 'answer' to a very similar question! I got over that, so here I am (again), looking for guidance (gentle preferred, any accepted)!

So, I recently came across a post on Stack Overflow, during a **Review Queue**, on which there was a number of seriously dodgy issues. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195040/web-based-bio-metric-attendance-system) (though it's been removed by moderators). I used the "Custom" flag to alert mods to the fact that the poster had already stated, "I know this will be removed" and, also, that he had posted an email address, which had then been edited out, and he then commented adversely on that edit.
I flagged this as, "possibly needing direct moderator interaction with poster" because, being relatively new here, I wasn't sure what else to put.

The flag is now "declined" but with no explanation as to what I should have done. (But, of course, post has been deleted - see footnote!)

Another custom flag I recently made was also declined (and, BTW, I have no problem with that) but, in that case, a brief (but sufficient) explanation was given: It was a foreign language post, and I was advised to use "Unclear what you're asking" - no problem, as I'm on a learning curve.

For a newbie, I have a pretty decent 'flag weight', I think; however, I want to be as helpful as possible to this community, so any advice as to why a flag is declined would be appreciated.

Footnote: The (exact) content of my 'custom flag' message:

> The poster already knows/states that the post will be removed! He has
>   also responded to an edit that removed an email link. I think this
>   probably needs 'direct' moderator interaction with the poster.

As I said, I'm quite new here, so wasn't sure of the exact syntax/language/request I should be using.

Footnote (2): I've also noticed that the user account in question is now 'deleted' (non-existent)! Could be self-imposed but, considering there were other posts associated with said user, it looks like moderator 'interaction' to me.

Comment: In my personal opinion (not a moderator), it seems that both issues could've been (and were) addressed by the community via downvotes, close votes, and/or comment flagging. It may have been declined simply because it didn't explicitly require that a moderator get involved.

Comment: Your title says the flag was deleted. I'm pretty sure that's not something that happens. Flags get declined, disputed, or marked helpful, but I've never heard of one getting deleted..

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't declined with the reason: *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for spotting the typo - edited!

Comment: @NickA Yes, I'm sure! It was: "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it."

Comment: @Adrian That's not without explanation, the explanation is they found no evidence... admittedly it's an odd explanation!

Comment: @Nick - Its a canned response, not really an explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the question in your Triage review:

[image]

There is nothing on that question that we can't handle ourselves. Flag for closure, unclear / too broad/ off-topic - resource request, would all work. Cast a down vote so the next visitor doesn't go wondering what is awesome about it.

If you have the slightest idea the question could have value you could have gave it an edit by removing the meta noise from it as you have full edit privileges. Don't involve mods if it is not needed.

If you still insist you want to take a gamble then don't give the mod an option to decline. Instead of:

> "possibly needing direct moderator interaction with poster"

say:

> "Please close and delete this question as it will not have value, even if answered. I don't have close or delete privileges but it might not be obvious for regular reviewers that this post is not good"

Now I still doubt if Jon Clements would fall for that but if you run into one of those deletionist mods you might get lucky ....

Comment: Gosh, I hope someone talked to the 2 people that reviewed that as Looks OK!

Comment: Thanks for that! However, although this is what I saw **after I flagged**, it does not show the 'other' point, about the attached email and edit. I guess that requires higher rep and/or mod privileges to see. (The deletion happened almost while I was watching!)

Comment: @Adrian yeah, I still have an option open that you run into  bug but I only found a report that confirms that comment flags get declined when a user is destroyed. Regular flags should be marked helpful on post and/or account deletion. I wait for a mod to confirm what happened here.

Comment: Also, at the time, "user1209..." was shown as "John" (which, in itself, struck me as an unusual name).

Comment: Yeah, never trust "John", that is for sure.

Comment: @rene - Like I said, it's really no big deal! I'm perfectly happy that mods can "decline" my flags (or, indeed, that the Community can). I just think it would be nice if, in cases like this, a hint of guidance was given as to how to handle such cases in future - thus saving our precious/over-worked moderators even more time.

Comment: We can handle that on meta. Mods handle over 1000 flags a day. They don't have time to cherry pick a reason let alone write a custom one

Comment: Either way, I pinged a mod in the hope they have some time to give us a hint what really happened,

Comment: @rene - Hmm! How much rep do you need to "ping a mod?"

Comment: several million, actually.

Comment: I think I just found a way to do it by proxy! ;-)

Comment: what probably happened is what @rene (pinging rene) described: the custom flag was very confusing. We have a lot of flags so it was dismissed. Then the same moderator nuked the user into orbit for several violations.

Comment: There you have it, you need Jean to nuke both post and OP. No "interaction" needed ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the explanation. rene - thanks for your understanding and efforts. For the record, I now consider the whole matter "closed" and I shall (after some sleep) continue to work my way up the SO Reputation Ladder, hopefully acquiring many more "helpful flags" on that road.

Comment: @rene I wasn't the moderator who performed any of those 2 actions (or I would have answered instead of assuming things in comments). But your guidance is still valid

Comment: @Adrian you're welcome. Don't hesitate to visit meta if you have doubts or if you into that, join a chatroom that is open for moderation requests, like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  (we have a [tour](https://socvr.org/tour)) or [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room)

Comment: note that deleting account is technically a "direct moderator interaction with poster". Not sure of what "if you run into one of those deletionist mods you might get lucky" means. A good moderator won't delete a post just because a user says so with a persuasive text but will check the post contents & context.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I meant you. And yes, a good moderator won't delete a post just because a user says so. All in good spirit. Let's move on.

Comment: @rene if you're not happy with some moderator actions, you can flag accordignly or write a meta post about it. No need to generalize.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know the procedure and I'm fine how the moderation goes, for me nothing needs to change. My generalization is not a disqualification, of anyone, nor you personal.

Comment: I was the mod that declined, for pretty much the reasons that Rene describes here. I then looked at the user again to discover some other issues that necessitated removal of the account, and that had the side effect of all their downvoted questions without answers being deleted automatically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It has occurred to me that the 'edit' I mentioned may have been hard-wiped (i.e. totally removed, without trace) by an uber-mod (staff, CM), as it contained "personal information." This would then explain why you "found no evidence..."

Comment: @Adrian: no, if there was personal information that required removal, then that info would have been redacted (the revision altered). Us moderators can see if a post has been redacted; we can't see the original version, but redacted revisions are marked. Nothing was redacted here, the edit is *still in the post history*. Just because the user had added an email address, or that it was removed and they responded to that edit, did not make this a case where a moderator needed to intervene.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha! Which brings us full circle: It was largely because of that edit that I raised the custom flag. But it was curious: When I first came to the triage, I noticed the user's comment about his email being removed, so I went to look at the edit history. While I was doing so I (literally), that edit history vanished (before my very eyes, along with the user's comment) - which makes me think it was, as you put it, redaction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But we're going nowhere now! I completely accept that the flag was unnecessary, now that I'm learning a bit more about how the Community system handles things like downvotes and 'normal' flags.

Comment: @Adrian: sounds like you experienced the "this post has been deleted" state change then, when the account was removed that post went with it.